# Given a string, how do I check if it is a float?

Tags: python, string

I have to use python to read a file, this file contains combination of characters, numbers and other stuff.

After reading a single line from the file, how do I check if this line is an integer or a float? (I have to know this information that this line is an integer and float)

I have tried these string methods `.isdigit()`, `.isdecimal()`, `.isnumeric()`, it seems like these methods only return `True` when there are only all decimal numbers within the string.

Is there any method that can help me to do this task?

P.S.: Can't use `try` or any `exception` approach.

============== Content of my File =================

```
0
[Begin Description]
xxx
[End Description]
1.1
[Begin Description]
....
```

I want to know if the current line I am reading is integer 0 or float 1.1. That makes my question.

Comment: Why in the world can you not use `try`/`except`?

Comment: It's actually a homework question but I think this is kind of general to all novice, so I post in this general trend. Really sorry about that.

Comment: It is bad practice to **not** use `try`/`except` when there could be exceptions. That makes it a rather bad homework assignment.

Comment: Also, please show your code and your error messages, so that we have a chance to see what is happening.

Comment: Sorry about that I understand this is standard in the industry, but really can't use that from this homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is faster than `re`

although this is not type checking but as you are reading string 0 or 1.1 you can do simply like

```
line='1.1'
if '.' in line:
    print("float")
else:
    print("int")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use try and except:

But if you dont want to use it and need different way then use **regex**:

```
if re.match(r"[-+]?\d+(\.0*)?$", s):
   print("match")
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help

```
import re
s = "1236.0"
r = re.compile(r'[1-9]')
r2 = re.compile(r'(\.)')
if re.search(r,s) and re.search(r2,s):
    print("Float")
if re.search(r,s) and not re.search(r2,s):
    print("Integer")
```

Answer (score 2):

For each line in the file you can check with regex whether it is a float or int or normal string

```py
import re

float_match = re.compile("^[-+]?[0-9]*[.][0-9]+$")
int_match = re.compile("^[-+]?[0-9]+$")

lines = ["\t23\n", "24.5", "-23", "0.23", "-23.56", ".89", "-122", "-abc.cb"]

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()

    if int_match.match(line):
        print("int")
    elif float_match.match(line):
        print("float")
    else:
        print("str")
```

Result:

> int
>   float
>   int
>   float
>   float
>   float
>   int
>   str

How it works:
`int_match = re.compile("^[-+]?[0-9]+$")`

`^`: at the str beginning
`[-+]?`: optional + or -
`[0-9]+`: one or more numbers
`$`: end of string

`float_match = re.compile("^[-+]?[0-9]*[.][0-9]+$")`

`^[-+]?`: start with either + or - optional.
`[0-9]*`: any number of digits or none.
`[.]`: dot
`[0-9]+`: one or more digits 
`$`:end

Answer (score 1):

You could split it into words using .split() and use string methods.

Example Code (Note that split method argument should be changed to comma if you use it in floats instead of dot):

```
def float_checker(strinput):
    digit_res = None
    for part in strinput.split('.'):
        digit_res = True if part.isnumeric() else False
    if digit_res:
        return True
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print(float_checker(input('Input for float check (Stop with CTRL+C): ')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import re
line1 = '0'
line2 = 'description one'
line3 = '1.1'
line4 = 'begin description'
lines = [line1, line2, line3, line4] # with readlines() you can get it directly
for i in lines:
   if re.findall("[+-]?\d+", i) and not re.findall("[+-]?\d+\.\d+", i):
     print('int found')
   elif re.findall("[+-]?\d+\.\d+", i):
     print('float found')
   else:
     print('no numeric found')
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
int found
no numeric found
float found
no numeric found
```